# Serialize or Implode

Tags: php, performance, serialization, explode, implode

I need to store lots of two-dimensional arrays inside database and was not sure what to use: `serialize` or `implode`. So I did a few tests, to find out which one is working faster and came to the conclusion it was `serialize`:

```
Execution times: 1'000'000
Serialize: 1.4974119663239 seconds
Implode: 2.5333571434021 seconds
Explode: 4.0185871124268 seconds
Unserialize: 1.6835169792175 seconds
```

So the question: Why is *implode+explode* so much slower then *serialize+unserialize*?

PS: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197255/serialize-vs-implode) question already, but it is not exactly what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is that `explode`/`implode` operate on strings that's why, while `serialize`/`unserialize` output/input a string at the very ending/beginning. Probably the more strings you `implode` and the longer string you `explode`, the slower it is, have you tried?

Which to use I don't know, it depends if you later wish to handle output string, I think `serialize`d string is more difficult to parse. But to store it in database or file I'd use `serialize`.

Comment: That sounds somehow reasonable. And yes, the larger the array, the longer implode/explode works. I already tested that too.

Comment: @DainisAbols I meant that it is not linear dependency. Is `implode`ing four strings exactly 2 times slower than imploding two strings? I guess it's more; and imploding eight strings would take more time than imploding two strings four times (all the strings should be the same length of course).

Comment: `Implode 2 elements: 1.8937180042267 seconds`, 
`Implode 4 elements: 2.4380650520325 seconds`, 
`Implode 8 elements: 3.6058769226074 seconds`
Not exactly two times, but close to it, while serialize changes with the same progression type, but slower rate.

Comment: So I was wrong, imploding more elements is somehow faster. Then concatenating strings must be the weakest link.

Comment: @DainisAbols You could compare the implementation of the [**implode function**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/41433a52d69e81a8ed9ac8f357be239bd89ff3bb/ext/standard/string.c#L1129) with the [**serialize function**](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/642721b38a9c5ebf336c81027c0dafd6f9246bd6/ext/standard/var.c#L711)