# Save an arrayed input field as a long string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Hi guys I have an input field in my blade which is an array.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input_fields_wrap">
                    <label for="dependents">Dependents</label>
                    <button class="add_field_button btn btn-sm">+</button>
                    <input type="text" name="dependents[]" class="form-control input-sm">
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to save this as a long string separated by a comma every string. And ill save this in my database as dependents. Is it possible?

Comment: Any string can be saved in a database.

Comment: but i mean is that to save it as an array how can i make it as one string @u_mulder

Comment: What do you mean by `And ill save this in my database as dependents` ?

Comment: If "dependents" are actual records in a table, you're almost certainly better off creating a pivot table to maintain referential integrity. You'll avoid many headaches in the future when someone changes the code and forgets that there are arbitrary relationships stuffed into a string field.

Comment: But I'm planning to save it as a long string to be able to save it in one field

Answer (score 2):

Yes, possible. Use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) when `inserting` to database.

```
$dependents = implode(',', $request->input('dependents'));
```

And use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) when `retrieving` from database to `array`.

```
$dependents[] = explode(',', $db_items->dependents);
```

Comment: ill put that in to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with the help of `implode`

```
$data = implode(',',$dataArray);
```

---

**But I would like to recommend you to use** [`serialize()`](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/serialize.php)

```
$data = serialize($dataArray);
```

and to get actual array you can use

```
unserialize($data); // $data should be serialize
```

**You get fewer efforts when you're using associated/multidimensional array with key**

[Serialize or Implode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218827/serialize-or-implode)

Comment: Whats the difference of using implode and unserialize?

Comment: As much as i concerned, serialize won't concatenate array values as a comma separated value, right??

Comment: @Sohel0415 exactly. It saves entire array as serialize with the respective key on each element. Once we unserialize it will restore the array way it been

Comment: php serialize is probably the worst way to save it, unless you save an instance of a class. Data saved this way is impossible to edit outside of PHP without destroying it.  And even more impossible to search on.  Even JSON is preferable to that.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix when you save multi-dimensional array then it might usefull as i mentioned

Comment: I would use JSON in that case, because at least you could search using `LIKE '%field:value%'` serialize  will be like `{s3:foo}` or some crap. where `s` means string and `3` is the length making it near impossible to search, as I said.  And if you edit `foo` and make it `food` outside of PHP you will never be able to un-serialize the data, Whereas Json has no issue with such an edit.

Comment: None sir I just decided to make a textbox instead of arrayed input fields

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can implode/explode it.

Generally speaking saving data this way renders it almost impossible to search on. It's usually better to save it in a separate table as it's essentially a Many To One relationship.  That is up to you to decide, but I wouldn't do it just to "cut corners" as things like counting and grouping will suffer because indexing such a field offers much less performance benefit then a separate table.

That said, one suggestion I have is to add the deleimters to the front and back like this:

```
,1,2,12,13,145,
```

Why you ask.  Because consider this query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%1%'
```

Now if that list is `field` it will match any row that has a `1` anywhere.  This is probably not what you want.  Such as matching `23,215,54`.  So the simple solution is to add the delimiters to the front and back and the query as well like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%,1,%'
```

Now we are only matching fields with `,1,`, because we can include the delimiters in the search. It should be pretty obvious that `,1,` is not the same as `215`.

You have to think hard how you will use this data as you will be limited to searching and grouping using only queries that use `Like %data%` to match with.

You can simply add them by doing this:

```
 $var = ','.implode(',', $arr).',';
```

The good thing is there are easy ways to remove these extra delimiters, if you choose to use them:

```
$var = trim($var,',');
//then we would explode it 
$arr = explode(',', $var);
```

You can even do it right in the SQL with

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM field ) AS trimmed;
```

I would be vary careful in your choice of delimiters, if it's possible to have a `,` in the data at all chose something like `|` and make sure to strip the delimiter from input data otherwise you may never be able to separate the data properly in the future.

I typically use this method when I use tree data with a Materialized Path schema, but that's a story for another time...